# Associate number with contact?

Tags: 8.1, contacts, people

How do I associate a received call's number with a contact?

I used to be able to click on a number and associate it with a contact. But now that I've upgraded to Windows Phone 8.1, it seems if you click on the number it just dials it. If you bring-up the menu (by holding down on it), you can go to "Details" but then you can't click on it or copy the number to the clipboard.

You also can't interact or copy a number out of the Speed Dial.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To save a number from the call history to your contact list, do the following:

1. Tap on the little profile icon to the right of the phone number. This brings up the contact page for "Unknown contact".
2. Tap the Save icon at the bottom.
3. Choose an existing contact to add the number to. Alternatively, to add a new contact, tap the + icon at the bottom, then enter the name and tap the Save icon.